# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Space Exploration's [first moderator election](https://space.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: gerrit]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://space.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4591694269906944/0).

Comment: Congrats, @gerrit!

Comment: Congrats gerrit!

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Congratulations :)!

Answer (score 15):

Thank you for your trust!  I am looking forward to joining the other moderators in serving the community on Space Exploration.

Looks like I already joined, shortly is short indeed.

Comment: Congrats, gerrit! I look forward to working with you. :)

Comment: and I'm looking forward to being triply-moderated again, yay! In my opinion your moderation in Earth Science SE is exemplary; it's great that you've here as well.